# DDPG not converging

Tags: python, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning

I am trying to implement the deep deterministic policy gradients algorithm in tensorflow, but the policy isn't converging to anything remotely good. I am testing on the cartpole problem.

The critic loss decreases to 0 over time, and the actor gradients converge to 0 as well, yet the reward does not increase. It seems like the actor settles for a "constant" policy, where it pushes the cart in one direction until the episode fails. I used the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process to add noise, with sigma decaying over time, and the initial angle is random, so the agent gets good exploration of the state space.

Doing gradient ascent vs gradient descent on the actor doesn't seem to make a difference. There must be something very wrong somewhere, but I don't know how to find it.

This is the top level actor update:

```
            predicted_actions = actor.get_actions(session, replay_states)
            critic_action_gradients = critic.get_action_gradients(
                session, replay_states, predicted_actions
            )
            gradient_magnitude = actor.update_weights(
                session, replay_states, critic_action_gradients
            )
            actor.update_target_network(session)
```

This is `get_action_gradients` in the critic:

```
def get_action_gradients(self, session, states, actions):
    return [
        session.run(self.action_gradients, feed_dict={
            self.nnet_input_state: np.array([state], dtype=np.float32),
            self.nnet_input_action: np.array([action], dtype=np.float32),
        }) for state, action in zip(states, actions)
    ]
```

Where `self.action_gradients` is simply

```
    self.action_gradients = tf.gradients(self.output, self.nnet_input_action)
```

And this is the actor's `update_weights`:

```
def update_weights(self, session, replay_states, critic_action_gradients):
    # each row of actor_gradients is multiplied by the corresponding critic gradient
    # then take a column-wise average
    # shape of actor_gradients is len(replay_states) x 6, each column has the
    # shape of the corresponding network weight
    critic_gradients = np.array(critic_action_gradients).reshape((len(replay_states), 1))
    actor_gradients = np.array(self.get_param_gradients(session, replay_states))
    avg_gradients = (actor_gradients * critic_gradients).mean(axis=0)

    new_params = session.run(self.update_weights_ops, feed_dict={
        op: grad for op, grad in zip(self.gradient_placeholders, avg_gradients)
    })

    return sum(np.sum(x) for g in avg_gradients for x in g)
```

The graph operations to update the weights are:

```
    self.network_params = [self.weights_1, self.bias_1,
                           self.weights_2, self.bias_2,
                           self.weights_3, self.bias_3]
    self.param_gradients = tf.gradients(self.output, self.network_params)

    self.gradient_placeholders = []
    self.update_weights_ops = []
    for param in self.network_params:
        gradient_placeholder = tf.placeholder(shape=param.shape, dtype=tf.float32)
        update_op = param.assign_add(self.learning_rate * gradient_placeholder)

        self.gradient_placeholders.append(gradient_placeholder)
        self.update_weights_ops.append(update_op)
```

Comment: did you figure it out by any chance?

Comment: @MoneyBall unfortunately no, I didn't :(

Comment: Hi, did you success to do anything ? I am trying to do the same for a humanoid task, I can take a look in your code if you want, if you have it in an online versioning tool. Helping you can help me pointing out my mistake, as well.

Comment: are you using 4 networks?  local and target for both actor and critic?  And then using a `soft_update`, ie. polyak averaging to update the target network so that it lags the local network by `new_weights = self.tau * local_weights + (1 - self.tau) *target_weights`
`target_model.set_weights(new_weights)` where tau is a number between 0 and 1 (closer to 1?)

Comment: fyi, openai's spinningup documentation explains DDPG quite well

Answer (score 0):

Try using epsilon-greedy policy for exploration instead of Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process noise

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.